# MySQL Community Server installation on CentOS using Chef

Tags: mysql, centos, chef-infra

I try to install **MySQL Community Server** on **CentOS7** using Chef mysql cookbook from supermarket:
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mysql

My cookbook files:

**metadata.rb**

```
depends 'mysql', '~> 8.0.4'
```

**default.rb**

```
mysql_service 'db_some_data' do
  port '3306'
  version '5.7'
  initial_root_password 'abc123'
  action [:create, :start]
end
```

I executed:

```
berks install
kitchen test -d never
```

and got following error:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[mysql-community-server]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::Package
-------------------------
No candidate version available for mysql-community-server

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_server_installation_package.rb

     17:       package package_name do
     18:         version package_version if package_version
     19:         options package_options if package_options
     20:         notifies :install, 'package[perl-Sys-Hostname-Long]', :immediately if plaform_family?('suse')
     21:         notifies :run, 'execute[Initial DB setup script]', :immediately if platfom_family?('suse')
     22:         action :install
     23:       end
     24:

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_server_installation_pckage.rb:17:in `block in <class:MysqlServerInstallationPackage>'

    yum_package("mysql-community-server") do
      package_name "mysql-community-server"
      action [:install]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :package
      cookbook_name "obiwan"
      version "5.7.11-1.el7"
      flush_cache {:before=>false, :after=>false}
    end

    Platform:
    ---------
    x86_64-linux
```

It looks like this issue: https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql/issues/443

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may need to use a different cookbook for this as the command below doesn't show mysql-community-server in the centos 7 repo. Perhaps try the mariadb cookbook.

```
yum provides mysql*
```

However if you really have to install mysql-community-server, you probably need to modify your recipe to look like so

```
execute 'mysql-community-repo' do
 command 'yum localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm
 action :run
end

 mysql_service 'db_some_data' do
  port '3306'
  version '5.7'
  initial_root_password 'abc123'
  action [:create, :start]
 end
```

Keep in mind, you may encounter some issues with the systemctl init script when starting mysql-community.

Comment: According to the docs of mysql cookbook it supports the CentOS 7

Comment: It really doesn't matter what the docs say. When u run a `yum provides mysql*` on a server and don't see any mysql-community-server results, then it means you cannot use yum to install it except you update your repository with one that has that package.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this setup with following changes:

**metadata.rb**

```
depends 'mysql'
depends 'mysql2_chef_gem'
depends 'database'
```

**default.rb**

```
mysql_client 'default' do
  action :create
end

mysql_service 'db_some_data' do
  port '3306'
  version '5.7'
  initial_root_password 'abc123'
  action [:create, :start]
end

mysql2_chef_gem 'default' do
  action :install
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists because https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mysql doesn't yet support for

```
cookbook 'mysql', '~> 8.0'
```

I added the following dependencies and it worked fine.

```
cookbook "yum-mysql-community", '~> 4.0.1'
cookbook 'mysql', '~> 6.0'
cookbook 'yum-centos', '~> 3.0.0'
```

Another thing to note here is to remember providing the **package_name** in the recipe. My recipe looks like this:

```
mysql_service 'foo' do
  port '3306'
  version '5.7'
  package_name 'mysql-server' 
  initial_root_password 'root'
  action [:create, :start]
end
```

Hope it helps!